# Power Automate flow to send message to multiple people using array n loop

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, microsoft-teams, power-automate

How to send a message as a Teams flow to multiple users.

I know we can do it using array, can someone help me how??

Answer (score 1):

You can send message to multiple users by creating a array and following below steps:

1. Initialise an array variable and add all the recipients to that array
2. Create an Apply to Each control and select the array variable you created in Step 1 for the "Select an output from the previous steps option"
3. Add an action "send message as the Flow bot" -> add your headline -> Select "Current Item" for the recipient -> add your message.